# Failing to identify right click event in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add some behavior for the right click event. Weirdly I simply cannot make the event handling work.

This is the jQuery code:

```
$('body').on('click', '#wrapper', null, function(ev){
    if (ev.which === 2 || ev.which === 3){
        alert("Here!");
    }
});
```

I think that the event is fired but it cannot be identified as a "rightclick". The alert message is never shown.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks you!

*LE: I am able to identify the left click event with `ev.which === 1`. So there is no problem there.*

Comment: what exactly is your problem? doesn't the click-event get fired at all? is there a problem wich `ev` or `ev.which` or one of the values?

Comment: @oezi the click event is fired but it cannot be identified. The alert message is not shown

Comment: @TGM actually, the click event works for left and middle click : http://jsfiddle.net/sNzsh/4/ anyway, I made some tests, ev.which = 0 with any click on IE8. ev.which = 1 for left click, not managed for middle click. Where did you find that it could be 2 or 3 ?

Comment: This is a tip, not a fix; you can omit the optional `data` parameter completely (`'click', '#wrapper', function(ev) {`), without using `null` (this behaviour is consistent with *all* optional parameters in jQuery)

Comment: @Shikiryu Firefox 12 with Firebug and Webdeveloper add-ons. I have no idea if those add-ons count for something in this matter.

Comment: @TGM I'm using FF4. A lot of difference between browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `click` use `mousedown`:

```
$('body').on('mousedown', '#wrapper', null, function(ev){
    if (ev.which === 2 || ev.which === 3){
        alert("Here!");
    }
});​
```

Comment: On FF4, 2 = middle click, 3 = right click, can't test for other browser from here.

Answer (score 1):

Using  javascript you can try this

```
document.onmousedown = ListenMouseClick
document.onmouseup = ListenMouseClick

function ListenMouseClick() 
{
if (window.event.button==2 )
    {
        alert('right click')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy using ternary operators and '`mousedown`' or '`contextmenu`'

http://jsfiddle.net/49Ldy/

```
$('body').on('mousedown','#wrapper',function(ev){
   var evt = ev.which === 3 ? alert('rightClick') : alert('someOtherButton');
});
```

or:

```
$('body').on('mousedown','#wrapper',function(ev){
    var evt = ev.which === 3 ? alert('rightClick') : (ev.which === 2 ? alert('auxClick') : alert('someOtherButton'));
});
```

or:

```
$('body').on('contextmenu','#wrapper',function(){
    alert('rightClick');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! that was it. I cannot make your answer final because someone gave me the same solution a little bit earlier. However, much appreciated.

Comment: @TGM No problem I was slow ;) Thanks, Happy coding