# dojo not trapping right-click event

Tags: javascript, dojo

In the code below, the right-click is not getting trapped. left-click works fine. This code was given in the dojo documentation. Can someone tell me why isRight is not working?  Essentially, when I right-click the element, I just get the browser's right-click menu, no console message is generated.

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/mouse.html

```
on(myNode,'click',function(e) {
        if (mouse.isLeft(e)){
          console.log("left click", e);
        } else if (mouse.isRight(e)){
          console.log("right click",e);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The browser right click context menu consumes the click event. It will work if you use 'mousedown' instead of 'click'. There are also many questions about right click detection in javascript that you can look into for alternate methods. For example: [Failing to identify right click event in Mozilla Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530769/failing-to-identify-right-click-event-in-mozilla-firefox).
The dojo/mouse module is mostly a utility wrapper over the usual event handling, so the information in these questions still applies.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot detect `mouse.isRight` when using event `click`. Instead you could use `mousedown` as in the following example:

https://jsfiddle.net/xgekrp5e/

```
require(["dojo/mouse", "dojo/on"], function(mouse, on) {
  on(document, "mousedown", function(evt) {
    if (mouse.isLeft(event)) {
      // handle mouse left click
      alert('MOUSE LEFT');
    } else if (mouse.isRight(event)) {
      // handle mouse right click
      alert('MOUSE RIGHT');
    }
  });
});
```